# Building and Installing Static Library with CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake

I have written a library in c++. I am using CMAKE to build the library. The library gets built but the header files are not getting installed. Below is how my CMakeLists.txt file looks like.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Strand)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(Headers [all the header files])
set(Sources [all the source files])

add_library(LibraryName STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})
install(TARGETS LibraryName DESTINATION /usr/lib)
```

In addition, the header files are quite a number. So I want all the header files to be installed into a directory, e.g. `usr/local/include/LibraryName/[all header files]`.

How can I achieve of fix this?

Comment: I went with this option
`install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION include/libraryname)`.

@squareskittles @Zaffy  However, the source and header files are organized into sub-directories, as a result when I try to use the library in a test application. The location of the header files cannot be resolved.

Comment: So you want to have different structure in project and after install?

Comment: @Zaffy Yes, I have used sub-directories within the `src` folder to organize related header and sources files.

Comment: It's a bit hacky but you could try to use `foreach` and call `install` on each header individually

Comment: I solved it using 

```
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/
        DESTINATION include/library
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
        )
```

using the suggestion from @squareskittles with a little tweak  to the directory.

Comment: great you solved your issue, now you can post your solution as an answer :)

Comment: @user2987773 Yes, If you have have solved your issue, please post an answer showing what you did to resolve it, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using `install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ DESTINATION include/library FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h" )` using the suggestion from @squareskittles with a little tweak to the directory